# Python - Text in form disappears

Tags: python, html, forms

In the following code below, I would like to text to stay in the form when the submit button is pressed. Currently the text disappears when submit is pressed.

Here is a tutorial link I've been following:
https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs253/l-48736183/e-48754026/m-48717294

```
import webapp2

form = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Unit 2 Rot 13</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Enter some text to ROT13:</h2>
        <form method = "post">
            <textarea name="text" value="%(word)s" style="height: 100px; width: 400px;"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

"""

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write_form(self, word=""):
        self.response.out.write(form % {"word": word})

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()

    def post(self):
        string = self.request.get("word")
        self.write_form(string)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = self.request.get("text")
```

since your form item name is `text`

this harkens back to the fact that you should use good identifiers ...

since you have no post variables named `word` ... trying to get that post variable gives an empty string